# Vapoursynth installation problems

Tags: linux-mint, python, python3

I am trying to install SVP (SmoothVideo Project) on Linux Mint 19.1 and I am running into problems with Vapoursynth installation. When I try to do the part "Building 3rd-party apps from sources -> Vapoursynth -> # build Vapoursynth! -> make -j4" (found in here: https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/SVP:Linux) I run into an error:

```
Fatal error: can't create src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-cachefilter.o: Permission denied
```

Here is the full code:

```
  CXX      src/core/libvapoursynth_la-boxblurfilter.lo
  CXX      src/core/libvapoursynth_la-cachefilter.lo
  CC       src/core/libvapoursynth_la-cpufeatures.lo
  CXX      src/core/libvapoursynth_la-exprfilter.lo
rm: cannot remove 'src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-cpufeatures.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-cachefilter.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-boxblurfilter.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-exprfilter.o': Permission denied
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-cpufeatures.o: Permission denied
Makefile:1322: recipe for target 'src/core/libvapoursynth_la-cpufeatures.lo' failed
make: *** [src/core/libvapoursynth_la-cpufeatures.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-boxblurfilter.o: Permission denied
Makefile:1472: recipe for target 'src/core/libvapoursynth_la-boxblurfilter.lo' failed
make: *** [src/core/libvapoursynth_la-boxblurfilter.lo] Error 1
In file included from src/core/exprfilter.cpp:38:0:
src/core/jitasm.h: In constructor ‘jitasm::detail::ResultT<float, 4>::ResultT(float)’:
src/core/jitasm.h:8533:52: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
   ResultT(const float imm) : val_(Imm32(*(uint32*)&imm)) {}
                                                    ^~~
src/core/jitasm.h: In member function ‘void jitasm::detail::ResultT<double, 8>::StoreResult(jitasm::Frontend&, const jitasm::detail::ResultDest&)’:
src/core/jitasm.h:8608:67: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     f.mov(f.dword_ptr[f.rsp - 8], *reinterpret_cast<uint32*>(&imm_));
                                                                   ^
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-cachefilter.o: Permission denied
Makefile:1479: recipe for target 'src/core/libvapoursynth_la-cachefilter.lo' failed
make: *** [src/core/libvapoursynth_la-cachefilter.lo] Error 1
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create src/core/.libs/libvapoursynth_la-exprfilter.o: Permission denied
Makefile:1486: recipe for target 'src/core/libvapoursynth_la-exprfilter.lo' failed
make: *** [src/core/libvapoursynth_la-exprfilter.lo] Error 1
```

I have installed the latest Python and Cython and that fixed some of my problems, but this problem still persists. I guess I should somehow give permission for it, but I don't know how, since I am quite new to the Linux world.

EDIT: I fixed this by running 'sudo make clean', for some reason 'make clean' did not clean it all the way. But now I am faced with a new problem. Something called "vspipe" keeps throwing error. Here is the error code:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        # If we are not using VSScript, do nothing.
        if self.single:
            return
        _environment_state.current = _env_current_stack().pop()

    def __eq__(self, other):
   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

src/cython/vapoursynth.pyx:133:4: Special method __eq__ must be implemented via __richcmp__
  CXX      src/vspipe/vspipe.o
Makefile:2019: recipe for target 'src/cython/vapoursynth.c' failed
make: *** [src/cython/vapoursynth.c] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Did you run some of the build as root only to then try to re-build using a non-privileged user?

Comment: Doesn't anyone know how to fix this? I have googled vspipe error but have found no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that Cython is out of date.  Use pip3 to update it.

```
pip3 install Cython
```

Comment: Wow that fixed the problem. Thank you so much!